# How to import links from a website to google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to import urls from https://www.mastersportal.com/ranking-country/82/united-states.html to get all the links of best universities in USA.

However, when I use the importXML formula, like importXML("url", "//td[@class='OrganisationListing']/@href"), it doesn't work.

What should I do to fetch the links with google sheet import formula?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help:

```
=importXML("https://www.mastersportal.com/ranking-country/82/united-states.html", "//table//tr//a/@href")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I can't believe that I just read the post [link]shorturl.at/wDJK3 on your blogger and then you answered my question here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve all hyperlinks from `https://www.mastersportal.com/ranking-country/82/united-states.html`.

In this answer, `//td[@data-title='Universities']/a/@href` is used as the xpath.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.mastersportal.com/ranking-country/82/united-states.html","//td[@data-title='Universities']/a/@href")
```

#### Result:

In the current stage, it seems that 258 hyperlinks are retrieved.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now, I do know what's wrong with my formula.